# Where Do I Set the Eden Space?

Tags: tomcat, configuration, java-8, memory-pool, metaspace

## Issue Summary :

Memmory size displayed near **PS Eden Space** is 639.5 MB  **WHILE** JAVA_OPTS contains `-Xms2558m -Xmx2558m` (2.5G) .

---

## Details :

After creating seten.sh file , i add this line :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms2558m -Xmx2558m -XX:PermSize=2558m -XX:MaxPermSize=2558m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Then , i monitor the UI of Application server to check this increase of memory is for what

[image]

I was wondred: Why when i browse to my application why **PS Old Gen** remains stable while **PS Eden Space** consume memory quickly . However , Memmory size displayed near **PS Eden Space** is 639.5 MB .

## How to increase **PS Eden Space**? What option should i use known that we use Java8 ?

When i set `-Xms2558m` : Is it too much known that my app is a grails application(includes spring framework,spring security,...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues:

`-Xms` sets the initial Heap space and has nothing to do with Eden space. That's what the JVM allocates on startup. If more is required, it allocates up to `-Xmx` later, but this applies to the total heap space, not one of the GC generation spaces (those will be part of the heap)

You can configure the ratio of young and old generation with `-XX:NewRatio=`. Check the documentation for your JVM, if it's Oracle's [this might suffice](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html), others might have better links. You'll find a lot of GC tutorials and articles all over the net.

When you read them: as far as I'm concerned, Young and Eden are often used synonymously.

A permanent generation space of 2.5G sounds like waaaaay too large - and you should use CATALINA_OPTS to set the tomcat configuration, not JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: "Eden and 2 survivor spaces together are called young space." according to [this](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html).

Comment: @Olaf Kock, One error i wanted to correct in your post A permanent generation space of 2.5G (This is not PermanentGen or PermGen this is called Old Gen) aditionally perm gen concepts are replaced by meta space from java 8 onwards, Young gen is combination of Eden space and Survivor state (s0) and (s1)